# List the running process in the current directory

Tags: macos, terminal, ps

Is there a possible way to use the ps command to list all the current running process in the current directory? For example, I have a, b, and c.exe (c program )program stores in the same directory, and I want to only list all of these three processes when I am running them on the terminal.

Comment: What operating system? I assume Linux (or something Unix based) since you said `ps` but then you said `c.exe`...

Comment: I am using the Mac OS X.

Comment: I have not understood.... Let's say you have a directory named "dir" containing 4 files: "a", "b", "c" and "d" but only "a", "b" and "c" are executable while "d" is only readable. Now you have "a" running and "d" executed via "bash d". What do you want to see?

Answer (score 3):

```
# you can use pwd between "`", to execute it, and get value
ps -ef | grep "`pwd`"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
dir=`pwd`
ps -ef | grep "$dir"
```

Comment: So I guess I have to enter "ps -ef | grep pwd"?

Comment: no,  you must use pwd between "`", to execute it, and get value

Comment: @A.ISSA Try this: create a file containing just one instruction: "sleep 60". Make this file executable (chmod 750) and run it in background. Now run the commands you suggest here above. What do you think you will get?

Comment: you are right, in this cas, we can use : ps -ef | grep "sleep"